# localstorage returns 11 on localstorage[key] += 1

Tags: javascript, numbers, local-storage

With the below code I make a localstorage variable with the key of a quote = 1 if it isn't defined. However, when it is eventually called again with the same quote key it becomes 11 and not 2 even with the Number() function in place.

```
if (typeof localStorage[quote] == "undefined") {
    localStorage[quote] = Number(1);
} else {
    localStorage[quote] += Number(1);
}

alert(localStorage[quote]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it is becoming "11" not 11.  Wrap parseInt() or Number() around the retrieval:

```
localStorage[quote] = Number(localStorage[quote]) + 1;
```

Edited per comments below.

From MDN (emphasis mine):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

> Description The DOM Storage mechanism is a means through which **string
>   key/value pairs** can be securely stored and later retrieved for use

Comment: `Number(1)` is unnecessary, can just be `1`.

Comment: @dfsq I agree, but you don't know what the rest of the user's code is...that may be a consistent or correct thing to do.

Comment: If  so then `Number(localStorage[quote])` might be better. We don't know that it's necessarily an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Because localStorage store by string.
typeof window.localStorage.getItem(quote); // "string";

So "1" + 1 =  "11".

You need to convert to number , if you want to store number.

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 2):

`+` is an operator for numbers (add two numbers) as well as the concatenation operator for string (concatenate string two to string one), depending on the type of operands

In your case, localStorage[key] will always return a string, so the concatenation operator will be used. And `"1" + 1 == "11"`

Therefore, you should convert the retrieved value to int before using the `+` operator on it

```
localStorage[quote] = parseInt(localStorage[quote], 10) + 1;
```